# Http request returns just an HTML comment

Tags: android, jsoup, postman

I'm using the following code to make a request to my client's website (http://unionmangas.com/leitor/Kuroko_no_Basket/275):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements pageElements = document.select("div.item > img.img-responsive");
```

However the only response I get from `get()` is:

```
<!--bool(false)
-->
```

If I use a tool like Postman (Chrome Application) the result is the same. How can I get the HTML that is rendered when I open using the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `user agent` string to your request (I am using FF, but you should use the same string as your own browser) -

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0")
            .get();
```

Now `document.html()` contains the `HTML` of the page.

Comment: I've tried with Chrome for Android user agent and yours too. All that I get is `<html><head></head> <body>  <!--bool(false)--> </body></html>`

Comment: That;s very odd. After the `get` statment I did `System.out.println(document.html());` and got the whole page. It begins like this - <html lang="en">
 <head></head> 
 <body style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000">
  ?
  <!--bool(false)
-->  but it continues - meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  and so on...